# Removing contract failed: [Error Code: 1056] (RemoveContract) is not authorized: removing contracts requires authorization from specific accounts

Tags: onflow-cadence

Using flow-cli, if I run `flow accounts remove-contract HelloWorld --network testnet --signer testnet-account` I get the above error. I created the contract using the same account but unable to remove it from testnet.

I read something about using `auth accounts` to remove contracts but couldn’t find any relevant examples showing its usecase. Any suggestions?

Do let me know if I can share any more information.

flow version: 0.41.0
account address: 0xf6827b3c1293b661

I am using this guide as reference to remove contract from testnet. https://developers.flow.com/tools/flow-cli/account-remove-contract

Answer (score 0):

Currently, testnet does not allow the removal of contracts, we have made contract removal temporarily permissioned on Testnet – just like it already is on Mainnet.
you can find more details in this post.
https://forum.onflow.org/t/testnet-is-running-secure-cadence/3213